# Extract years from string in Excel

Tags: excel, text-extraction

I have a list of coverage dates without a recurring pattern. For example, I have the following strings:

```
Available from 1951 until 1984;

Available from 1964 volume: 2 issue: 1 until 2002 volume: 20 issue: 4;

Available from 1958 volume: 1 issue: 1;

Available from 1970 issue: 24 until 1989 issue: 110;  Available from 1990 volume: 1 issue: 1 until 2001 volume: 12 issue: 4;
```

I am trying to extract only the years value into a different columns in Excel, for example:

```
Available from 1951 until 1984; -> 1951 | 1984
Available from 1964 volume: 2 issue: 1 until 2002 volume: 20 issue: 4; -> 1964 | 2002
Available from 1970 issue: 24 until 1989 issue: 110;  Available from 1990 volume: 1 issue: 1 until 2001 volume: 12 issue: 4; -> 1970 | 1989 | 1990 | 2001
```

(if possible, each year should appear in a different column)
Is there a way for me to extract the years? I thought of writing a VB code but I am honestly not fluent in VB.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(MODE.MULT(IF((TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($1:$50)-1)*999+1,999))="from")+(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($1:$50)-1)*999+1,999))="until"),SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1," ",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($1:$50))*999+1,999)),";","")*{1,1})),COLUMN(A:A)),"")
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Put in B1, Hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  Then copy/drag over and down.

This formula looks for `from` and `until` and pulls the next "word" as the return.  If that rule is not consistent then this will not work.

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant!
I'm still trying to figure out how it's built, as it has none of the functions I thought of using (except TRIM)!

Thank you very much